# I'm trying to understand how the keyword `this` and the method `call` work. It looks like a bug to my ignorant eyes

Tags: javascript, constants, this, call

```
function sum() {
    return this.a + this.b;
}
```

This function should find the values of a and b from the global scope and then add them together if there is no call. At first I set `a = 3, b = 4;`. If I then type `sum()` I get 7. If I update The values of a and b without declaring them to const. The value of `this.a` and `this.b` is reflected in `sum()`.

But when I type `const a = 10;` and then go ahead and run `sum()` it's value is still 7. Shouldn't the value be 14? I'm doing these calculations on console in google chrome if that matters.

[image: sample screenshot of the console]

Shouldn't the value of sum() be 13 now that a = 5? why is it still using the old value of a?

Comment: Don't use `this.a` to access a global variable, just use `a`. `this.a` will only work if the function is defined in sloppy mode, if it is called without a context, and the `.a` is actually a property of the global object (which `let`- and `const`-declared variables are not).